# Regular expression for NN-ARID-NNN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

What will be the *RegularExression* for this?

```
NN-ARID-NNN?
//N = Number
```

I have tried this `^[0-9/-0-9]+$`

Comment: Reminds of 99-ARID-640, University of Arid Agriculture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not matching the `ARID` at all and a character class will match in any order... You might want to use something more like this:

```
^[0-9]{2}-ARID-[0-9]{3}$
```

[Assuming that `?` is not in the actual string...]

If you want the first two digits to be within the range of `00` to `13`, then you can use the OR operator with `|` and a group:

```
^(?:0[0-9]|1[0-3])-ARID-[0-9]{3}$
 ^^^      ^      ^
  |      OR      |
  |              |
  +---- Group ---+
```

Breakdown:

```
^           Matches beginning of string
  (?:       Beginning of group
    0[0-9]  Matches 00 to 09 only
  |         OR
    1[0-3]  Matches 10 to 13 only
  )         End of group
-ARID-      Matches -ARID- literally
[0-9]{3}    Matches 3 digits
$           Matches end of line
```

When there is an option of matching `00`-`09` or `10`-`13`, the pattern just cannot match a blank. There's no way it will match if the numbers are not there.

Comment: Can I restrict that `[0-9]{2}` is less then 14?

Comment: @user3110335 Yup. You can use `^(?:0[0-9]|1[0-3])-ARID-[0-9]{3}$`.

Comment: ^[0-1]?[0-4]{0,1}-ARID-[0-9]{3}$

This worked for me.

Comment: @user3110335 Well, if that works for you, I guess it works. Note that this regex of yours won't match `09` or `05`, and will even match blanks. If it can be a single digit but not zero, then I would use `^(?:[1-9]|1[0-3])-ARID-[0-9]{3}$`

Comment: Yes, mine matches blanks too, 
Yours works fine...
Can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you :(
I was asking to explain yours.
^(?:0[0-9]|1[0-3])-ARID-[0-9]{3}$

Comment: @user3110335 Oh, that's okay :) I added a little bit of explanation to my answer, which hopefully helps!